# bugzilla doesn't deliver mails in "sendmail" mail delivery method but displays as mail sent

Tags: email, bugzilla

bugzilla doesn't deliver mails in "sendmail" mail delivery method but displays as mail sent.

It worked fine previously.  What could have caused this?

Comment: I tried giving nc mailrelay.netcon.in 25.

Comment: I tried giving "nc mailrelay.netcon.in 25". It doesnt display anything.